# When does the daily arcade playlist reset?

Tags: overwatch

What time each day does the arcade's "changes daily" playlist actually change? I was playing it at 11pm mountain time last night, and it's still the same the next morning later at 925am.

Comment: Pretty sure it's based in PST

Comment: @n_palum why would it be the same at 10pm PST as at 825 PST the next day then?

Comment: Not sure, no where I've seen specifically lists the time it resets. The rewards reset at 00:00 UTC on Tuesday so maybe it's supposed to reset at 00:00

Answer (score 2):

It resets at 0:00 UTC, or 7:00 PM EST/4:00 PM PST.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/7ejvbd/what_time_does_the_daily_arcade_change/ - Plus tested myself? Today the Winter event ended at 7PM EST.